# Creating custom image in Docker when the changes after base image is not command-line

Tags: docker

I downloaded a docker-compose file and started the images. The application is built of multiple images.

Now I want to make specific changes to it from the UI interface and save the result as a separate image. In this system, the changes will be as Dlls and database changes.

The articles and posts in this forum I have seen are catering to the scenario where the changes have been made only through the command line.

It will be helpful if you can direct me in the right direction.

Comment: I'd probably approach this by checking out the source code, make whatever change you need to the application without involving Docker, run its unit test suite, and then build new images once you think it works.  You can't usually modify the existing images, and depending on the language the images won't contain editable source code.  Is there a specific problem you're running into?